# MySQL: WHERE query not working in PHP; working in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm baffled by this problem I'm having running a query through php. I'm hoping someone here can help me figure out what's going wrong. I want to query some data and filter it so only the results that were added after 11:00:00 on the day before and before 11:00:00 on the day the query are retrieved. Seems basic enough.

So I've made this code(abbreviated version):

```
 $result = myql_query("SELECT id_order, date_add, firstname, lastname FROM orders
 WHERE date_add >= '" . $yesterday . " 11:00:00' AND date_add <= '" . $today . " 11:00:00';");

 $today = date("Y-m-d");
 $yesterday = date('Y-m-d', time()-86400);
```

... but I'm given every row, not just the ones between those dates and times. What makes this really weird to me is that if I echo that same $result string, and then paste the results directly as a mySQL query it gives me what I'm looking for.

Any help figuring out why this isn't working as php would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Provide us the actual values for `date_add`, we cannot read your minds. Also, this exact code will not even work - it makes sense to not simplify your code that much.

Comment: by the way, why did you define your time variables after your query?

Comment: Sorry, @zerkms. the values for `date_add`, are `2014-10-20 12:13:22, 2014-10-25 15:13:48, 2014-10-27 15:13:48` but Yohanes question gave me the hint I needed to figure out what was wrong. I need the variables defined before the query is made. Duh! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it
But try this

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("yesterday"));

$result = mysql_query('SELECT id_order, date_add, firstname, lastname FROM orders
WHERE date_add BETWEEN "' . $yesterday . ' 11:00:00" AND "'. $today . ' 11:00:00"');
```

And don't forget that those 2 variables have to be in the file before the query.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Define your variables before query.

Code should be:

```
 $today = date("Y-m-d");
 $yesterday = date('Y-m-d', time()-86400);

 $result = myql_query("SELECT id_order, date_add, firstname, lastname FROM orders
                        WHERE date_add >= '" . $yesterday . " 11:00:00' AND 
                              date_add <= '" . $today . " 11:00:00';");
```

> **Note:** Always print your query if your query is not giving you expected
>   result. That will give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "**BETWEEN**" Operator.

Comment: I would really like to vote your answer up, but you didn't provide an example.